# Is it HATEOAS compliant? GET same address with different results

Tags: api-design, hateoas

Is it HATEOAS-compliant to expose resources via `GET /resources` when this call returns a different resource each time?

For example to distribute resources across clients, according to some internal algorithm, meaning I don't want every client to receive always the same resource (let's say I coded a 'phrase of the day' server and distribute them randomly):

First call: GET /resources

```
200 OK
{
  "_links" : { "self" : "/resources/1" },
  "data" : "foo"
}
```

Second call: GET /resources

```
200 OK
{
  "_links" : { "self" : "/resources/2" },
  "data" : "bar"
}
```

Or is it better to provide a `GET /resources/chooser` that returns a `links` object to the concrete resource and make a second call?

Comment: GET should be idempotent - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods

Comment: According to your link 
"idempotence refers to the state of the system after the request has completed, so while the action the server takes (e.g. deleting a record) or the response code it returns may be different on subsequent requests"

Comment: You've misread it - that refers to `PUT` & `DELETE`. A `GET` request `should not have side effects, beyond relatively harmless effects such as logging, caching, the serving of banner advertisements or incrementing a web counter.` A web counter here is something that tracks the amount of visitors.

Comment: Then again, it doesn't say anything about responses. According to that you can respond anything as long you don't change the state on the server.

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of your `GET /resource` endpoint, what is it doing exactly?

Comment: It's supposed to distribute resources across clients, according to some internal algorithm, meaning I don't want every client to receive always the same resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HATEOAS is about following links. So until you expose these operations (except getting the API root) as links with metadata (like "self" in your example), it is fulfilling the HATEOAS constraint. There is no standard about the URI structure, just suggestions. For example it is easier to route calls for named resources. Note that for the REST client the URI structure does not matter, because it checks the link metadata to decide whether it want to follow a link.

In your current example the `/resources` should have a self descriptive metadata, for example `rel=chooser` or something like that. So the client will know what is it about. I think your URI structure violates the URI standard, because the path describes the hierarchical part of the URI, but in the current case there is no hierarchy between the `/resources` and the `/resources/1`, `/resources/2` URIs. So if you want to create and alias or with your choice of words "chooser", it is much better to use the `/resources/chooser` or `/resources?chooser=true`.

Comment: @renatoargh Yes, there is, but it has nothing to do with the URI structure. E.g. `resources/adsfgf432342`, `cars/3546473`, `cars?id=3546473` can mean the exact same thing. You can describe a structural template by using URI templates.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question, assuming /resource is the entry point of your application, or you have a root resource that links to /resource, it is certainly meets the HATEOAS constraint.

Questioning if this is RESTful architecture or not is a bit trickier.  One thing is you must absolutely be indicating the result is NOT cacheable. Using HTTP this would be with an HTTP Header.  That is assuming that every request to /resource would get a new resource...maybe the same users get the same resource..than you could allow cacheing.

I've always been confused about the idempotence of GET.  You can search with good using GET and if they update something the same GET may change the result.  Of course that's something else changing the state...but i remember reading that they'll change rankings based on clickthroughs of results..which is a GET too...so??

If it were my API, and it was not a big deal to make the request a POST only, i probably would go with POST an 406 a GET.  If i really needed GET than i would't worry about it too much.